# WordPress - How to fix WooCommerce breadcrumbs on shop category page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

In WooCommerce > Settings > Products, I have set "Shop Page Display" to "Show subcategories" - so that on my main shop page (http://example.com/shop/) only categories (and no individual products) are shown.

I have also used [this code snippet](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/show-product-categories-in-wooframework-breadcrumbs/) to make the product categories show in my breadcrumbs as my theme uses WooTheme's "Simplicity" theme as its parent.

The problem I have is that the breadcrumbs are not displaying correctly. The breadcrumbs look fine on the shop home page...
You are here: Home > Products

But when I then click on a category from that page, the breadcrumbs change to...
You are here: Home > Chocolate

...when it should really be...
You are here: Home > Products > Chocolate

To confirm the issue, when I then click on a product, the breadcrumbs look fine again...
You are here: Home > Products > Chocolate > Vegan Chocolate bar

Does anyone know how I can fix the problematic breadcrumbs on the categories page?

As this seems like a bug, I have asked WooCommerce for their support, but they're not willing to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing? Did you solve this? I have exactly the same problem... :/

Comment: If I remember correctly, WooThemes said they would be fixing this in a forthcoming release - clearly, not so forthcoming though... Would probably be worth you raising a ticket with them (and maybe pointing them to this SO page).

Comment: I have made some more progress on this. I have it working on the product pages. see my second answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your funtions.php file

```
// Breadcrumbs Display Category Name
// ====================================================================

function get_breadcrumb_category( $cat ) {
   $post = get_post( $post->ID );
   $post_type = $post->post_type;
   $taxonomy = $cat;

   $f_categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
   $f_category = $f_categories[0];

   if ( $f_category->parent != 0 ) {
      $f_category_id    = $f_category->parent;
      $parent_array     = get_term_by('id', $f_category_id, $taxonomy, 'ARRAY_A');
      $f_category_name  = $parent_array["name"];
      $term_link        = get_term_link( $f_category_id, $taxonomy );
   } else {
      $f_category_id    = $f_category->term_id;
      $f_category_name  = $f_category->name;
      $term_link        = get_term_link( $f_category_id, $taxonomy );
   }

       if ( $f_categories && ! is_wp_error($f_categories) ) {
          return '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $f_category_name . '</a>';
       } else {
         return '';
   }
}

function x_breadcrumbs() {

    if ( x_get_option( 'x_breadcrumb_display', '1' ) ) {

      GLOBAL $post;

      $is_ltr         = ! is_rtl();
      $stack          = x_get_stack();
      $delimiter      = x_get_breadcrumb_delimiter();
      $home_text      = x_get_breadcrumb_home_text();
      $home_link      = home_url();
      $current_before = x_get_breadcrumb_current_before();
      $current_after  = x_get_breadcrumb_current_after();
      $page_title     = get_the_title();
      $blog_title     = get_the_title( get_option( 'page_for_posts', true ) );
      $post_parent    = $post->post_parent;

      if ( X_WOOCOMMERCE_IS_ACTIVE ) {
        $shop_url   = x_get_shop_link();
        $shop_title = x_get_option( 'x_' . $stack . '_shop_title', __( 'The Shop', '__x__' ) );
        $shop_link  = '<a href="'. $shop_url .'">' . $shop_title . '</a>';
      }

      echo '<div class="x-breadcrumbs"><a href="' . $home_link . '">' . $home_text . '</a>' . $delimiter;

        if ( is_home() ) {

          echo $current_before . $blog_title . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_category() ) {

          $the_cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ), false );
          if ( $the_cat->parent != 0 ) echo '<a href="'.get_permalink(102).'">'.get_the_title(102) .'</a>';
          echo $current_before . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $current_after;

        } elseif ( x_is_product_category() ) {

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $shop_link . $delimiter . $current_before . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $current_after . $delimiter . $shop_link;
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_product_tag() ) {

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $shop_link . $delimiter . $current_before . single_tag_title( '', false ) . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . single_tag_title( '', false ) . $current_after . $delimiter . $shop_link;
          }

        } elseif ( is_search() ) {

          echo $current_before . __( 'Search Results for ', '__x__' ) . '“' . get_search_query() . '”' . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {

          if ( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) == is_front_page() ) {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            if ( $is_ltr ) {

              $f_category = get_the_category();

              if ( $f_category[0]->parent != 0 ) {
                 $f_category_id = $f_category[0]->parent;
                 $f_category_name = get_cat_name( $f_category_id );
              } else {
                 $f_category_id = $f_category[0]->term_id;
                 $f_category_name = $f_category[0]->name;
              }

              echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $f_category_id ) . '">' .     $f_category_name . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
            } else {
              echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $delimiter . '<a href="' . get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) . '">' . $blog_title . '</a>';
            }
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_portfolio() ) {

          echo $current_before . get_the_title() . $current_after;

        } elseif ( x_is_portfolio_item() ) {

          $link  = x_get_parent_portfolio_link();
          $title = x_get_parent_portfolio_title();

          if ( $v = get_breadcrumb_category('portfolio-category') ) {
            $portfolio_category = $delimiter . $v;
          } else {
            $portfolio_category = '';
          }

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a>' .     $portfolio_category . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after .     $portfolio_category . $delimiter . '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a>';
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_product() ) {

         if ( $v = get_breadcrumb_category('product_cat') ) {
           $product_category = $delimiter . $v;
         } else {
           $product_category = '';
         }

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $shop_link . $product_category . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $product_category . $delimiter . $shop_link;
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_buddypress() ) {

          if ( bp_is_group() ) {
            echo '<a href="' . bp_get_groups_directory_permalink() . '">' . x_get_option( 'x_buddypress_groups_title', __( 'Groups', '__x__' ) ) . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . x_buddypress_get_the_title() . $current_after;
      } elseif ( bp_is_user() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . bp_get_members_directory_permalink() . '">' . x_get_option( 'x_buddypress_members_title', __( 'Members', '__x__' ) ) . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . x_buddypress_get_the_title() . $current_after;
      } else {
        echo $current_before . x_buddypress_get_the_title() . $current_after;
      }

    } elseif ( x_is_bbpress() ) {

      remove_filter( 'bbp_no_breadcrumb', '__return_true' );

      if ( bbp_is_forum_archive() ) {
        echo $current_before . bbp_get_forum_archive_title() . $current_after;
      } else {
        echo bbp_get_breadcrumb();
      }

      add_filter( 'bbp_no_breadcrumb', '__return_true' );

    } elseif ( is_page() && ! $post_parent ) {

      echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $post_parent ) {

      $parent_id   = $post_parent;
      $breadcrumbs = array();

      if ( is_rtl() ) {
        echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $delimiter;
      }

      while ( $parent_id ) {
        $page          = get_page( $parent_id );
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $page->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( $page->ID ) . '</a>';
        $parent_id     = $page->post_parent;
      }

      if ( $is_ltr ) {
        $breadcrumbs = array_reverse( $breadcrumbs );
      }

      for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $breadcrumbs ); $i++ ) {
        echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
        if ( $i != count( $breadcrumbs ) -1 ) echo $delimiter;
      }

      if ( $is_ltr ) {
        echo $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
      }

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {

      echo $current_before . single_tag_title( '', false ) . $current_after;

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {

      GLOBAL $author;
      $userdata = get_userdata( $author );
      echo $current_before . __( 'Posts by ', '__x__' ) . '“' . $userdata->display_name . $current_after . '”';

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {

      echo $current_before . __( '404 (Page Not Found)', '__x__' ) . $current_after;

    } elseif ( is_archive() ) {

      if ( x_is_shop() ) {
        echo $current_before . $shop_title . $current_after;
      } else {
        echo $current_before . __( 'Archives ', '__x__' ) . $current_after;
      }

    }

      echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but we've switched to the `Canvas` theme since I asked the question, so cannot test.

Answer (score 0):

starting from the `} elseif ( x_is_product() ) {` and finishing at the `} elseif ( x_is_buddypress() ) {`

```
  } elseif ( x_is_product() ) {

$product_categories = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
$parent = '';
$sub_category = '';

foreach ($product_categories as $category ) {
$term_id = $category->term_id;
$term_name = get_term( $term_id, 'product_cat' );

 if ( $category->parent != 0 ) {
  $sub_category .= $parent_id . '<a href="'.home_url().'/product-category/'.$term_name->slug.'/">' . $term_name->name . '</a>' . $delimiter ;
 } else {
   $parent .= '<a href="'.home_url().'/product-category/'.$term_name->slug.'/">' . $term_name->name . '</a>' . $delimiter ;
 }
}

if ( $v = get_breadcrumb_category('product_cat') ) {
       $product_category = $delimiter . $v;
     } else {
       $product_category = '';
     }

  if ( $is_ltr ) {
if(is_array($product_categories)){                               
    echo $shop_link . $product_category . $delimiter . $sub_category . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;                
}
else {
    echo $shop_link . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
}            
 } else {
  echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $delimiter . $shop_link;
}

} elseif ( x_is_buddypress() ) {
```